# Running 4k laptop monitor in 1080p

Tags: windows-10, high-dpi, 4k-resolution, 1080p, high-resolution

I'm running Windows 10 on a Dell XPS 15 (9550) running Windows 10. The built-in laptop monitor is 4k resolution. However due to compatibility issues I want to run the display in 1080p mode.
When I set the resolution to 1920x1080 and scaling to 100% (no scaling) the screen is blurry, even compared to a 1600x900 screen.
I suspect this is a issue with the way Windows 10 perform scaling.

Is this normal?
Is it possible to scale without making the image blurry (or less blurry)?

Graphics cards:
- Intel HD-Graphics 530
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M

Comment: Depends on what you consider normal? But, yes. it is normal.

Comment: It looks like something lower than the 1600x900. The image is not sharp. Is it possible to make it sharper (with something else than the Windows settings panel)?